# Facing synchronous call issues in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, q

I have two service calls which I want to execute synchronously in order.But that is not happening even when I am using promises.

Controller:

```
vm.nominationSVC.zipping(vm.fileSelected, vm.selectedCategoryId).
            then(function (response: any) {   //Zipping
                vm.nominationSVC.downloadDocument("documents.zip");  
            }).
            then(function (response: any) {
                var deffered = vm.$q.defer();
                for (i = 0; i < vm.rowSelectedLength; i++) {
                    vm.objDownloadHistory.Nomination_Id = vm.nominationIdSelected[i];
                    vm.objDownloadHistory.FilePath = vm.fileNamesSelected[i];
                    vm.promises.push(vm.nominationSVC.updateDownloadHistory(vm.objDownloadHistory));
                }
               //  vm.$q.all(vm.promises).then(function () {
              //       console.log("sdsd");
             //   });
            }).
           then(function (response: any) {
         vm.getNomiantionList();
        });
```

the method vm.nominationSVC.updateDownloadHistory(vm.objDownloadHistory) doesn't execute fully and comes down to other .then method i.e vm.getNomiantionList();

I tried working with $q.all also as mentioned in commented code.But still I am unable to resolve this issue.

Service Method:

```
updateDownloadHistory(objDownloadHistory: SpotAward.DownloadHistory)
        {
        var vm = this;
        var url: any;

        var deferred = this.$q.defer();
        url = this.BaseUrl + 'DownloadHistory/UpdateDownload';
        if (url !== null) {
            this.$http.post(
                url,
                JSON.stringify(objDownloadHistory),
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }
            ).then(function (result: any) {
                if (result.data > 0)
                    deferred.resolve(result.data);
            }).catch((data) => {
                deferred.reject(data);
            });
        }


        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the expected behavior should be :
 - Execution of vm.nominationSVC.zipping
 - When the promise returned by vm.nominationSVC.zipping is resolved, the three following then() will be called **sequentially**. That's not a good practise.

You should use only one then() call per promise, which allows you to visualize the chain of callbacks. Try something like :

```
vm.nominationSVC.zipping(vm.fileSelected, vm.selectedCategoryId).
        then(function (response: any) {   //Zipping
            vm.nominationSVC.downloadDocument("documents.zip");  

            var deffered = vm.$q.defer();
            var promises = [];
            for (i = 0; i < vm.rowSelectedLength; i++) {
                vm.objDownloadHistory.Nomination_Id =vm.nominationIdSelected[i];
                vm.objDownloadHistory.FilePath = vm.fileNamesSelected[i];
                promises.push(vm.nominationSVC.updateDownloadHistory(vm.objDownloadHistory));
            }

           $q.all(promises).then(function () {
                 vm.getNomiantionList();
           });
        });
```

In this case, the 3 old then() calls will be called sequentially (I'm supposing here that vm.nominationSVC.downloadDocument is synchronous and doesn't return a promise).

I hope it will help